# String Split using pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string

[image]

I tried using the following code:

```
df1['company_etrim']=df1['company_trim'].str.replace(r'[0-9()%]', "").str.join('')
```

and got a result as the above image which excluded 3 from 3M CO and 3 from SBIO INC.
But I want to include them.

my expected result should return
any numbers between or starting or ending, but it shouldn't return any numbers in between () and shouldn't return().

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is all like that in your column, you do not need a regex, you may `rsplit` the column with a space *once* and get the first part:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'company_etrim':['3M CO (95%);', '3SBIO INC (96%);']})
>>> df1['company_etrim'].str.rsplit(' ', n=1).str[0]
0        3M CO
1    3SBIO INC
Name: company_etrim, dtype: object
```

If you want to remove percentages inside parentheses followed with `;` you can use a regex approach:

```py
>>> df1['company_etrim'].str.replace(r'\s*\(\d+%\);', '', regex=True)
0        3M CO
1    3SBIO INC
Name: company_etrim, dtype: object
```

The `\s*\(\d+%\);` regex matches

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `%\);` - a `%);` string.

Comment: I'm surprised you couldn't find a duplicate for this!

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I do not remember a post that is related to removing percentage values inside parentheses in Pandas. I am not sure the first non-regex approach will work across the whole dataframe column, it is an assumption only. If we want to close the question, then it should be "unclear", as duplicate search might take too much time. (I mean this is not a pure regex issue, the Python code needs adjusting here, too, thus I cannot close it with some generic regex duplicate).

Comment: What I've done in the past is find the appropriate python/regex question (with the correct pattern) and then close it to that, plus an existing question with pandas `.str.replace`, and then leave a brief comment. Similar to the way I closed https://stackoverflow.com/q/69064979/7758804. I don't personally feel like there needs to be all regex examples for pandas too, because there are already great regex answer by you (and others). However, you've been doing this awhile, so I leave it to your discretion. Best Regards.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney This way of closing has been constantly rejected and disputed by the RavinderSingh13 & co. team (and among them are several gold regex bagde holders). I stopped closing like this unless the 2 issues are too evident (evident means "very common" and "broadly covered on SO") and there is a general consensus these close reasons are canonical posts. I also know the Fourth Bird's opinion (also a great regex expert) on such questions, he would not close this one with a generic duplicate. I leave that to others then.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`str.replace(\([0-9]+\%\), "")`